# What is the difference between Google Cloud Vision API and Mobile Vision?

Tags: api, mobile, machine-learning, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I have been playing with [cloud vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). I did some label and facial detection. During this Google I/O, there is a session where they talked about [mobile vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/). I understand both the APIs are related to machine learning in Google Cloud.

Can anyone explain (use-cases) when to use one over another?

what sort of applications that we can build by using both ?

Comment: I just ran some tests on my project, cloud vision API for text seems to give better results than the android API for the same input.

Comment: Also, when I checked there is no text (scanning from credit cards) API available for iOS. So, I couldn't even test.

Comment: If you're doing credit card scanning, the mobile API will work well (from my tests) with cards with plain-ish background. If you want to handle fancy cards, you'll probably want to use the cloud API. You could also use the mobile API, then fallback to cloud if the result failed. The mobile API is instantaneous, so worth trying for UX.

Comment: Thanks Badoualy. I checked the Google website (https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview) and I couldn't find text API(Credit Card Scanning) for iOS. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Probably doesn't exist on iOS, meaning you will have to use the cloud API (with its 1000 free usage/month)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be many various sets of application requirements and use cases befitting one of the APIs or the other, so the best decision is to be taken on an individual basis.

It is worthwhile noting that the Mobile Vision offers facial recognition, whereas Cloud Vision API does not. Mobile Vision is geared towards the likeliest use-cases to be encountered in a mobile device environment, and encompasses the [Face](https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts), Barcode Scanner and Text Recognition APIs.

A use case for both the Mobile Vision set and the Cloud Vision API would require face recognition as well as one of the features specific to the Cloud Vision API, such as the detection of inappropriate content in an image.

Comment: I know Cloud Vision is not free, is Mobile Vision free to use in commercial product ?

Comment: According to current Firebase pricing(https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) on device API for MLKIT is free

Answer (score 1):

Google is planning to "wind down" Mobile Vision as I understood.

> The Mobile Vision API is now a part of ML Kit. We strongly encourage you to try it out, as it comes with new capabilities like on-device image labeling! Also, note that we ultimately plan to wind down the Mobile Vision API, with all new on-device ML capabilities released via ML Kit. Feel free to reach out to Firebase support for help.
> https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction?hl=en